# sqlite table member not found

Tags: android, sqlite

i am getting an error in following sqlite database code can anyone correct me what i am doing wrong?? below is the LOGCAT for accessing issue.

on another note i want my user to register with official email id not with google yahoo or hotmail, how can i restrict use of free emails??

DBHelper

```
public class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "membersdb";
    private static final String DATABASE_TABLE = "members"; // this is your
                                                            // table name
    private static final String KEY_ROW_ID = "_id";
    private static final String KEY_USERNAME = "username";
    private static final String KEY_PASSWORD = "password";
    private static final String KEY_FULLNAME = "fullname";
    private static final String KEY_EMAILS = "emails";

    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

    private static final String DATABASE_CREATE = "CREATE TABLE "
            + DATABASE_TABLE + " (" + KEY_ROW_ID
            + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + KEY_USERNAME
            + " TEXT NOT NULL , " + KEY_EMAILS + " TEXT NOT NULL , "
            + KEY_PASSWORD + " TEXT NOT NULL , " + KEY_FULLNAME
            + " TEXT NOT NULL);";

    public DBHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);

    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE);

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int arg1, int arg2) {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS members");
        onCreate(db);

    }

}
```

**DBAdapter**

```
public class DBAdapter {
    private static final String DATABASE_TABLE = "members";
    public static final String KEY_ROW_ID = "_id";
    public static final String KEY_USERNAME = "username";
    public static final String KEY_PASSWORD = "password";
    public static final String KEY_FULLNAME = "fullname";
    public static final String KEY_EMAILS = "emails";

    SQLiteDatabase mDb;
    Context mCtx;
    DBHelper mDbHelper;

    public DBAdapter(Context context) {
        this.mCtx = context;
    }

    public DBAdapter open() throws SQLException {
        mDbHelper = new DBHelper(mCtx);
        mDb = mDbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        return this;
    }

    public void close() {
        mDbHelper.close();
    }

    public long register(String username, String password, String fullnames, String emails) {
        ContentValues initialValues = new ContentValues();
        initialValues.put(KEY_USERNAME, username);
        initialValues.put(KEY_PASSWORD, password);
        initialValues.put(KEY_FULLNAME, fullnames);
        initialValues.put(KEY_EMAILS, emails);

        return mDb.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, initialValues);
    }

    public boolean Login(String username, String password) throws SQLException {
        Cursor mCursor = mDb.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + DATABASE_TABLE
                + " WHERE username=? AND password=?", new String[] { username,
                password });
        if (mCursor != null) {
            if (mCursor.getCount() > 0) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

**MemberRegister activity**

```
public class MembersRegister extends Activity {
    DBAdapter dbAdapter;
    EditText txtUserName, fullname, authcodes, txtemail;
    EditText txtPassword;
    Button btnLogin;
    Button btnRegister;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.register);

        authcodes = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.auth_code);
        fullname = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.registerName);
        txtUserName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.userName);
        txtPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.registerPassword);
        txtemail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.registerEmail);
        btnRegister = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnRegister);
        dbAdapter = new DBAdapter(this);
        dbAdapter.open();

        btnRegister.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(txtUserName.getWindowToken(), 0);
                imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(txtPassword.getWindowToken(), 0);
                imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(fullname.getWindowToken(), 0);
                imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(txtemail.getWindowToken(), 0);
                try {

                    String username = txtUserName.getText().toString();
                    String password = txtPassword.getText().toString();
                    String fullnames = fullname.getText().toString();
                    String emails = txtemail.getText().toString();
                    long i = dbAdapter.register(username, password, fullnames,
                            emails);
                    if (i != -1)
                        Toast.makeText(MembersRegister.this,
                                "You have successfully registered",
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                } catch (SQLException e) {
                    Toast.makeText(MembersRegister.this, "Some problem occurred",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                }

            }
        });
    }
}
```

LOGCAT

```
09-30 10:34:00.807: E/Database(368): Error inserting username=hello emails=hello password=hello fullname=hello
09-30 10:34:00.807: E/Database(368): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: table members has no column named emails: , while compiling: INSERT INTO members(username, emails, password, fullname) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?);
09-30 10:34:00.807: E/Database(368):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCompiledSql.native_compile(Native Method)
09-30 10:34:00.807: E/Database(368):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCompiledSql.compile(SQLiteCompiledSql.java:92)
09-30 10:34:00.807: E/Database(368):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCompiledSql.<init>(SQLiteCompiledSql.java:65)
09-30 10:34:00.807: E/Database(368):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:83)
09-30 10:34:00.807: E/Database(368):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.<init>(SQLiteStatement.java:41)
09-30 10:34:00.807: E/Database(368):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.compileStatement(SQLiteDatabase.java:1149)
09-30 10:34:00.807: E/Database(368):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insertWithOnConflict(SQLiteDatabase.java:1569)
09-30 10:34:00.807: E/Database(368):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insert(SQLiteDatabase.java:1426)
09-30 10:34:00.807: E/Database(368):    at com.ideals.ideal.DBAdapter.register(DBAdapter.java:42)
09-30 10:34:00.807: E/Database(368):    at com.ideals.ideal.MembersRegister$1.onClick(MembersRegister.java:50)
09-30 10:34:00.807: E/Database(368):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2485)
09-30 10:34:00.807: E/Database(368):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9080)
09-30 10:34:00.807: E/Database(368):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
09-30 10:34:00.807: E/Database(368):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
09-30 10:34:00.807: E/Database(368):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
09-30 10:34:00.807: E/Database(368):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
09-30 10:34:00.807: E/Database(368):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-30 10:34:00.807: E/Database(368):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
09-30 10:34:00.807: E/Database(368):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
09-30 10:34:00.807: E/Database(368):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
09-30 10:34:00.807: E/Database(368):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

thanks in advance

Comment: Did you previously deploy the app and then add the new column emails?

Comment: yes i am running on emulator, added email tab later

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your create SQL starts with CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS. So my idea is you added emails column while the device has already had that table. If this is the case then just reinstall the app - it will delete the DB, so you can be sure the table will be created with that column.

Comment: restarting emulator with wipe data

Comment: I hope it will take after Reinstall

Comment: thanks when using wipe data same is working perfectly

Answer (score 0):

Delete and Create the "members" Table. Maybe you have an older version in store.

Answer (score 0):

You need to uninstall your application install it again. The `onCreate` method is only called one. For `onUpgrade` to trigger, you need to increase the database number.

Also, you probably don't want to delete the table in `onUpgrade` as the users will lose all the data.

Answer (score 0):

Uninstall the app from emulator and run again.

Answer (score 0):

may be you should change database name

from this

```
 private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "membersdb";
```

to

```
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "members.db";
```